# Возможно ли изменить порядок вывода вложенных блоков?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть три блока, причем второй и третий объединены (возможно в этом проблема).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="a">
      A
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="b">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При разных разрешениях получаю результат

[image: md]

[image: sm1]

Вопрос: Можно ли изменить стили или верстку, чтобы на мобильных устройствах блок А оказывался между блоками В и С
[image: sm2]

Comment: Как вариант, можно сделать копию А между В и С и на декстопных скрывать

Comment: Разве у бутстрапа нет изменения порядка? Как по мне проще использовать гриды, будет куда гибче.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае, для данного набора элементов решение может выглядеть так:

1. Задаем основному контейнеру свойство `display:flex`, чтобы управлять порядком его дочерних элементов через св-во order
2. Убираем обертку B и С из дерева доступности, свойством `display: contents` — теперь его наследники становятся дочерними элементами основного контейнера
3. Ставим элемент В первым по порядку при помощи отрицательного значения `order:-1`

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-12.col-md-4 {
  display: contents;
}

.b {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
    <div class="a">
      A
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="b">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      C
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```